# "ORA-00904 invalid identifier" when adding foreign key constraint

Tags: oracle, ddl

I'm trying to create a "diagnosis" table(last table), but something is wrong with the 2 lines of code that creates Foreign Key. I'm sure that's where the problem lies because when I comment them out, I can create the table. The first 4 tables can be created with no errors, so no problem with them. Thank you for reading my question.

I have tried to spot some syntax errors but to no avail.

```
CREATE TABLE nurse(
nurse_ID number(5) not null,
nurse_name varchar2(20),
nurse_number number(10),
nurse_address varchar2(50),
CONSTRAINTS nurse_pk PRIMARY KEY (nurse_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE medicine(
med_ID number(10) not null,
med_name varchar2(30),
med_type varchar2(20),
exp_date date,
dose_lim float,
med_components varchar2(50),
CONSTRAINTS med_pk PRIMARY KEY (med_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE in_patient (
in_pat_ID number(5) not null,
in_pat_name varchar2(20),
in_pat_add varchar2(50),
in_pat_dob date,
in_pat_history varchar2(100),
in_mode_payment varchar2(20),
in_start_date date,
in_end_date date,
CONSTRAINTS in_pat_pk PRIMARY KEY (in_pat_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE out_patient (
out_pat_ID number(5) not null,
out_pat_name varchar2(20),
out_pat_add varchar2(50),
out_pat_dob date,
out_pat_history varchar2(100),
out_mode_payment varchar(20),
out_date_of_visit date,
CONSTRAINTS out_pat_pk PRIMARY KEY (out_pat_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE diagnosis(
dia_ref number(12) not null,
dia_type varchar2(20),
dia_date date,
dia_result varchar2(8), --Either Negative or positive.
CONSTRAINTS dia_pk PRIMARY KEY (dia_ref),
--one of the following is going to be null when you insert rows into this table since one diagnosis can only be associated with a single patient
CONSTRAINTS dia_out_fk FOREIGN KEY (out_pat_ID) REFERENCES out_patient (out_pat_ID),
CONSTRAINTS dia_in_fk FOREIGN KEY (in_pat_ID) REFERENCES in_patient (in_pat_ID)
);
```

I expected that the table can be created with no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `diagnosis` table refers to `out_pat_ID` and `in_pat_ID` as columns which should serve as foreign keys, but these columns don't actually exist in the table definition.  Try adding them as one possible fix here:

```
CREATE TABLE diagnosis (
    dia_ref number(12) NOT NULL,
    dia_type varchar2(20),
    dia_date date,
    dia_result varchar2(8),
    out_pat_ID number(5),
    in_pat_ID number(5)
    CONSTRAINT dia_pk PRIMARY KEY (dia_ref),
    CONSTRAINT dia_out_fk FOREIGN KEY (out_pat_ID) REFERENCES out_patient (out_pat_ID),
    CONSTRAINT dia_in_fk FOREIGN KEY (in_pat_ID) REFERENCES in_patient (in_pat_ID)
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, that makes sense.. Now it works. This question of mine was a rather silly one..

Answer (score 0):

diagnosis table need add out_pat_ID and in_pat_ID column

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE nurse(
>
>     nurse_ID number(5) not null,
>     nurse_name varchar2(20),
>     nurse_number number(10),
>     nurse_address varchar2(50),
>     CONSTRAINTS nurse_pk PRIMARY KEY (nurse_ID)
>
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE medicine(
>
>     med_ID number(10) not null,
>     med_name varchar2(30),
>     med_type varchar2(20),
>     exp_date date,
>     dose_lim float,
>     med_components varchar2(50),
>
>     CONSTRAINTS med_pk PRIMARY KEY (med_ID)
>
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE in_patient (
>
>     in_pat_ID number(5) not null,
>     in_pat_name varchar2(20),
>     in_pat_add varchar2(50),
>     in_pat_dob date,
>     in_pat_history varchar2(100),
>     in_mode_payment varchar2(20),
>     in_start_date date,
>     in_end_date date,
>     CONSTRAINTS in_pat_pk PRIMARY KEY (in_pat_ID)
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE out_patient (
>
>     out_pat_ID number(5) not null,
>     out_pat_name varchar2(20),
>     out_pat_add varchar2(50),
>     out_pat_dob date,
>     out_pat_history varchar2(100),
>     out_mode_payment varchar(20),
>     out_date_of_visit date,
>     CONSTRAINTS out_pat_pk PRIMARY KEY (out_pat_ID)
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE diagnosis(
>
>     dia_ref number(12) not null,
>     dia_type varchar2(20),
>     dia_date date,
>     dia_result varchar2(8), --Either Negative or positive.
>     out_pat_ID number(5) not null,
>     in_pat_ID number(5) not null,
>
>     CONSTRAINTS dia_pk PRIMARY KEY (dia_ref),
>     --one of the following is going to be null when you insert rows into this table since one diagnosis can only be associated with a single patient
>     CONSTRAINTS dia_out_fk FOREIGN KEY (out_pat_ID) REFERENCES out_patient (out_pat_ID),
>     CONSTRAINTS dia_in_fk FOREIGN KEY (in_pat_ID) REFERENCES in_patient (in_pat_ID)
>
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2c85d821c74b83b4beb73b6f8acfc49)*

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. That makes sense... I did add them in my table and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing only one patient per diagnosis, then you should have a `check` constraint as well.  Your comment and data structure are out-of-sync:

```
CREATE TABLE diagnosis (
    dia_ref number(12) not null,
    dia_type varchar2(20),
    dia_date date,
    dia_result varchar2(8), --Either Negative or positive.
    out_pat_ID number(5),
    in_pat_ID number(5),
    constraint chk_diagnosis_pat_id
        check ( (out_pat_id is not null and in_pat_id is null) or
                (out_pat_id is null and in_pat_id is not null)
              ),                 
    constraint dia_pk primary key (dia_ref),
    --one of the following is going to be null when you insert rows into this table since one diagnosis can only be associated with a single patient
    constraint dia_out_fk foreign key (out_pat_ID) references out_patient (out_pat_ID),
    constraints dia_in_fk foreign key (in_pat_ID) references in_patient (in_pat_ID)
);
```

That said, separate tables for in-patient and out-patient do not look correct.  Or, at the very least, you need a `persons` table with information about a person over time.  Then you can have separate "appointments"  and "registrations" to determine if they make an out-patient appointment or register for in-patient care.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. And thank you for not only answering my question but also for giving me further corrections and suggestions. I'm going to try adding the check constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to define single-column constraints inline as part of the column definition. Then you don't have to repeat the column name, and for FK constraints you can let the column inherit its parent's datatype so it is less error-prone.

```
create table in_patient
( in_pat_id          number(5) constraint in_pat_pk primary key
, in_pat_name        varchar2(20)
, in_pat_add         varchar2(50)
, in_pat_dob         date
, in_pat_history     varchar2(100)
, in_mode_payment    varchar2(20)
, in_start_date      date
, in_end_date        date
);

create table out_patient
( out_pat_id         number(5) constraint out_pat_pk primary key
, out_pat_name       varchar2(20)
, out_pat_add        varchar2(50)
, out_pat_dob        date
, out_pat_history    varchar2(100)
, out_mode_payment   varchar(20)
, out_date_of_visit  date
);

create table diagnosis
( dia_ref            number(12) constraint dia_pk primary key
, dia_type           varchar2(20)
, dia_date           date
, dia_result         varchar2(8)
, dia_out_fk         references out_patient (out_pat_id)
, dia_in_fk          references in_patient (in_pat_id)
);
```

If `dia_result` can only be `'POSITIVE'` or `'NEGATIVE'` then I'd suggest adding a check constraint to enforce this.

Probably some more columns could be defined as `not null`. It's a good idea to define every possible constraint you can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and good suggestions. I will try adding some constraints where appropriate.